Aiogram bot.sendMessage
Помогите разобраться.
main.py

bot = Bot(token="..")
dp = Dispatcher()
dp.include_router(user_router)




user_router.py

@router.message(F.text.in_(someVar))
async def someDef(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text="text")
    await bot.sendMessage(chat_id="", text="")

не могу понять как вне main файла использовать bot с его методами. Для удобства проэкт разбит на несколько файлов.
Задача:
бот общается с пользователем в личном чате. Пользователь что-то выбирает и в этот момент бот отправляет краткую выдержкуу в отдельный канал.
Пример:
пользователю нужно запустить скрипт на сервере. Бот через меню уточняет параметры. Послие выборки параметров бот пишет в ЛС что начал делать, и в этот же момент в статически заданный канал присылается инфа "Пользователь Вася запустил someScript на сервере таком-то."

вопрос то собственно в чем? спрашиваете "как вне main файла использовать bot", в задаче и в примере у вас совсем другое указано

@ZxNuClear я не разобрался в наследовании видимо. До сих пор не понимаю как bot: Bot передается в другие файлы, в частности в декорированные функции. Обычно у меня выскакивает ошибка что отсутствует обязательный аргумент bot Если его попытаться импортировать, будет ошибка зацикливания. Если создать новый обьект в текущем файле - другая ошибка. Я уже голову сломал.. Буду признателен за любую наводку что почитать, дабы закрыть фундаментальные пробелы

Импортируем модули (Bot где он будет использоваться, а DefaultBotProperties в main.py)
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties

Добавляем дефолтный parse mode в main.py
bot = Bot(token="..", default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)))

Твой измененный someDef:
@router.message(F.text.in_(someVar))
async def someDef(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    mention = f'<a href="tg://user?id={message.from_user.id}">{message.from_user.first_name}</a>'
    server = "пельмени"
    script = "майонез"
    await message.answer(text="text")
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=-100XXXXXX,f"Пользователь {mention} запустил скрипт {script} на сервере {server}") 

Где chat_id=-100XXXXX вставляешь айди чата, но не убирай -100 в начале.
Также если захотишь отправлять в отдельную тему супергруппы, то добавь в bot.send_message
message_thread_id=Айди темы


как ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос "как вне main файла использовать bot"?

@ZxNuClear я думаю он хочет отправить сообщение в группу, но не понимает как. Думает что нужно из main.py импортировать переменную bot

даже если он импортирует Bot в файле user_router.py - это все равно ничего не даст, так как main.py не будет знать о существовании хэндлеров в файле user_router.py. А все потому, что автор как минимум неправильно импортирует роутер в основной файл

@Алексей всё правильно понимаете. Я пытался сделать from main import bot и получал ошибку зацикливания.
async def someDef(message: Message, bot: Bot) если я правильно понимаю, bot - обязательный аргумент. Откуда он сюда передается? Или как? Направьте на статью или расскажите пожалуйста.

@Максим он импортируется с aiograma. В main.py вы вводите для библиотеки bot токен, а чтобы бот запустился с этим токеном то выполняется await dp.start_polling(bot). То есть стартуете поллинг бота с токеном "...". Так как вы импортируете с main.py bot, то даже так не сможете. Если переменная в функции main(), а вы импортируете её с файла main.py то её не будет. А если смогли бы то в хендлере Бот не сработал, потому что вы импортируете переменную, а не модуль с функциями.
